# Data from form submit fail to insert in database row

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to insert a new product in my products database using ajax php and mysql, pdo. The form lies in a different html file and is loaded in a bootstrap modal as soon as i press the add product button.

Below is the form

```
<div class="container">
     <form class="form" id="insert-product" method="POST">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-label" for="name">Product Title</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="ptitle"  tabindex="1" required>
              </div>              
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-label" for="message">Product Description</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc" name="description" tabindex="2" required>                               
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-label" for="email"> Price</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" tabindex="2" required>
              </div>                            
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-label" for="subject">Picture of Product</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="picture"  tabindex="3">
              </div>                            

              <div class="text-center">
                  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-start-order">SAVE</button>
              </div>
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>
```

This is the script which uses ajax to contact the php file. readProducts() is a simple function which fetch the data from the database.

```
   $('#insert-product').on('submit', function(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           $.ajax({
                    url: 'insertPro.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $('#insert-product').serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {

                        readProducts();
                    }

                 });
       })
```

This is the php file that inserts the data into the database. The connect.php is tested and working correctly.

```
<?php 
require_once('connect.php');

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $response = array();

    $query = "insert into products(id,name,description,img_file,price) values(:title, :description, :picture, :price)";
    $stmt = $DBcon->prepare( $query );

    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
    $stmt->bindParam(':description', $description);
    $stmt->bindParam(':picture', $picture);
    $stmt->bindParam(':price', $price);

    $title = $_POST["ptitle"];
    $description = $_POST["description"];
    $price = $_POST["price"];
    $picture = $_POST["picture"];

    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt) {
        $response['status']  = 'success';
        $response['message'] = 'Product Deleted Successfully ...';
    } else {
        $response['status']  = 'error';
        $response['message'] = 'Unable to delete product ...';
    }
}
```

This is my connect file.

```
<?php

    $DBhost = "localhost";
    $DBuser = "root";
    $DBpass = "";
    $DBname = "test";

    try{

        $DBcon = new PDO("mysql:host=$DBhost;dbname=$DBname",$DBuser,$DBpass);
        $DBcon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    }catch(PDOException $ex){

        die($ex->getMessage());
    }

?>
```

When i press the button to submit the data, ajax refreshes as it should but the record is not added in the table of my database.

Comment: Move the setting of `$title` etc in your PHP that inserts the data to before your calls to bind the data.

Comment: It doesn’t look like your “id” field is being populated correctly. If it’s auto incremented you should not include it in your query, or add a value for it in values()

Comment: @Dave `bindParam()` Binds a PHP variable to a corresponding named or question mark placeholder in the SQL statement that was used to prepare the statement. Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called.

Comment: **Please DONT amend errors out of your question once there is an answer**

Comment: You're right @RiggsFolly ... not sure what I was thinking. Thanks for setting things straight. It's always seemed odd to code things in that order so it still looks "wrong" to me even though it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the `id` column of the `products` table is an autoincrement column.

In that case you either leave it OFF the column list OR give it a value of NULL

So either

```
$query = "insert into products(name,description,img_file,price) 
                        values(:title, :description, :picture, :price)";
```

Or

```
$query = "insert into products(id,name,description,img_file,price) 
                        values(NULL, :title, :description, :picture, :price)";
```

Also at the end of this script you build a response but you never actually send it back to the AJAX Call

```
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt) {
    $response['status']  = 'success';
    $response['message'] = 'Product Deleted Successfully ...';
} else {
    $response['status']  = 'error';
    $response['message'] = 'Unable to delete product ...';
}
// add this line
echo $json_encode($response);
```

Then is you add `dataType: 'JSON',` to you AJAX parameters, you can process the results in `data` as a javascritp object

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'insertPro.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#insert-product').serialize(),
        dataType: 'JSON',
```

Comment: Indeed the id is AI but unfortunately that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: What does `readProducts();` do, as that is all you do on `success`

Comment: Th readProducts is a function that calls a file to load the records of the table. And as far as i know is working correctly because i can see the records divided in columns etc.

Comment: Having fixed the `id` bit, does a row get created on the database

Comment: No. The phpmyadmin does not display any records other than those i added manually. Also i don't want to use the responses right now.

Comment: Show the connection script as well please. Did you add `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` to the connection

Comment: Yes everything added. Shall i edit the post to add it?

Comment: Yes please, just for completeness

Comment: If you add the `echo $json_encode($response);` what do you see in the javascript debugger returned from the PHP

Comment: It does not show any errors or warnings, completely white.

Comment: F12 in the browser. Loads the developer window containing a javascript debugger. Set a breakpoint on this line `readProducts();` and then using the debugger look at the contents of `data`